# Segmentation fault - std::_Rb_tree

Tags: c++, gdb, segmentation-fault

I'm going through some crashes in my application and would like to know if anyone can help.

gdb:

http://pastebin.com/tW6HzY2Y
What can cause this? I'm using Ubuntu 10.04.3.

Edit:
Look likes the problem is here:

```
bool ChatChannel::removeUser(Player* player)
{
    UsersMap::iterator it = m_users.find(player->getID());
    if(it == m_users.end())
        return false;

    m_users.erase(it);

    return true;
}
```

This is odd, there was never any problem with this part. I do not know how to reproduce the error.

Comment: That's... far too little information to work with.

Comment: The problem is that you have a bug in your code.  But it's impossible to suggest what that could be, because you haven't shown any code.  Please consider creating a [**minimal test-case**](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Can you give me an example of what could cause this? I cant give the code i I dont know where is the problem.

Comment: It could be almost anything.  Somewhere, you have corrupted the internal state of your container, or you've passed some invalid arguments, or you've invoked undefined behaviour some other way.  I would suggest minimising the code, or running under e.g. Valgrind, or enabling checked containers.

Comment: If you are using collection that is supposed to be sorted, then make sure that the comparison function is correct. just a hint

Comment: if you put in 
gdb <name of your program> core 
you can get a better call-stack.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't much to go from as other suggested. The stack trace you linked to has nearly no information. However, there is a tiny bit which is safe to say: based on `this=0x38` you are trying to find something in an object which isn't a tree. My personal guess is that your data structure containing your `std::map<unsigned int, Player>` has this map after a couple of other members (which have a total size of 56 bytes) but you try to access this data structure via a `NULL` pointer. That is, although the segmentation fault happened in `std::_Rb_tree` the error isn't in the `std::map` implementation at all.

Answer (score 0):

Run your program under [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).  It will almost certainly spit out some error before the actual crash which may point more closely to the source of the error (as opposed to the collateral damage).

Answer (score 0):

Do not know when/where the pointer to Player is initilized/discarded. I would look at it very carefully. Raw pointers are headaches most of the time.
Please look at `player->getID()`. Perhaps the call to member function is done at invalid memory address.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).